# Numpy arrays for hours of the year

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm trying to do some calculations that require a `numpy` array of 365 days of the year with each of those days having 24 values for the hours of the day.

Should I write this as a nested list and then convert to an array or is there a way of doing it straight as an array?

Comment: you probably want a two dimensional (366,24) array. Also note that there are leap years with 366 days.

Comment: How are you planning to represent it? As date objects? As (hour, day) tuples?

Comment: I'd like to run a calculation on them as integers but the output will be floats, preferably a value for each hour of the year but in 366 seperate lists/array